# all days/all days of the week/all days a week

Tags: word-usage

> A)I read books **all days a week**.
>
> B)I read books **all days of the week**.
>
> C)I read books **all days**.

I was wondering if all these three sentences are correct.I know that I can use **every single day of the week** or  **every day** to express the same message ,but I want to know the correct way of using all+days here.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "correct". Syntactically, all your examples are "valid", but in practice native speakers wouldn't use any of them. Stick with *I read books every day*. Or *...every day **of the week*** if you have some special reason why you want to explicitly mention something so contextually obvious (what *other* kinds of days are there?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your valuable help.I didn't know it's not common to use these expressions.I assumed that **all days** is as common as **all day**.

Comment: No - ***all day*** and ***all days*** are very different. The first one is common (it means ***throughout the day***), but the second is uncommon  because we nearly always use ***every day*** in normal contexts. Using a "marked" (less common) form usually implies a less common ***meaning*** (the audience would be expected to notice the unusual phrasing, prompting them to think of what *specific* unusual meaning might be intended).

Comment: So, for example, *I don't have a fixed duty rota in my new job. I can be called in to work all days of the week* is at least "credible" because the more natural ***...every day of the week*** might be understood as meaning I (sometimes) have to work *all 7 days* in a single week. Whereas actually what I mean is that I might be required to work on any *single* day (weekends included), with no implication that this happens particularly often (I might only work on one or two days every month).

Comment: @FumbleFingers To be pedantic, as always, it could depend on context. For example: Albert: "I only drink beer on Fridays." Bob: "I drink beer every day of the week." Bob probably doesn't mean that he drinks beer every single day, just that he has no special day of the week for drinking beer that Al does.

Comment: @Jay: I think Bob in your example would more likely say *I drink beer **any** day of the week* - specifically *because* using ***any*** there would convey the intended sense unambiguously (his likelihood of drinking isn't related to "day of week"), whereas ***every*** would probably be misinterpreted as implying #he has a bit of a (daily) drink problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I don't want to get into an argument about it. I agree your wording would be better, but I think people routinely say it the way I gave it.